How to change the font (character) spacing in Powerpoint VBA Macro
I have this macro for altering the text. Though I also want to change the character spacing here to 'condensed' by 0.5. Is that possible?
Sub FormatText()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim textRange As textRange
    
    ' Loop through each slide starting from the second slide
    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If slide.SlideIndex > 1 Then
            ' Loop through each shape in the slide
            For Each shape In slide.Shapes
                If shape.HasTextFrame Then
                    If shape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                        For Each textRange In shape.TextFrame.textRange.Paragraphs
                            If textRange.Font.Size = 70 Or textRange.Font.Size = 72 Then
                                ' Apply formatting
                                textRange.Font.Size = 72
                                textRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin = 0.85
                            End If
                        Next textRange
                    End If
                End If
            Next shape
        End If
    Next slide
End Sub

I tried this but it didn't work: TextRange.Font.Spacing = 1

"it didn't work" doesn't tell us much about what happened when you tried that.

Cross-posted on answers.microsoft.com and answered there.

Here's the revised macro (also posted on answers.microsoft.com). The variables have been renamed to be more reliable (Dim shape as shape can confuse VBA), and the TextRange2 refers to the TextFrame2 object, so the Spacing property is available.
Sub FormatText()
    Dim oSlide As slide
    Dim oShape As shape
    Dim oTextRange As TextRange2

    ' Loop through each slide starting from the second slide
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If oSlide.SlideIndex > 1 Then
            ' Loop through each shape in the slide
            For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
                If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                    If oShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                        For Each oTextRange In oShape.TextFrame2.textRange
                            If oTextRange.Font.Size = 70 Or oTextRange.Font.Size = 72 Then
                                ' Apply formatting
                                oTextRange.Font.Size = 72
                                oTextRange.Font.Spacing = oTextRange.Font.Spacing - 0.5
                            End If
                        Next oTextRange
                    End If
                End If
            Next oShape
        End If
    Next oSlide
End Sub

